# Nokogiri - line feeds and carriage returns

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri as an XML builder.

The output XML is separated by line feeds, however our requirement is to have **both** line feeds and carriage returns.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Easest way is to `.gsub(/\n/,"\n\r")`. But it affect all `\n` in xml.

Comment: I guess that will solve the problem.  The system that expects `"\n\r"` should be able to cope even if it makes way into XML tag content.

Comment: Also note if actual lines read "\n\r" then they will become "\n\r\r" which is probably not the desired result.